# Image segmentation using kmeans algorithm in java

Tags: java

I am making java application that will detect the plant disease using image processing and neural network. But I am facing problem in segmenting the image based on the k-means algorithm in java. Actually I do not have idea how to segment the image. Please if somebody can help me with source code to segment the image in different clusters. Thank you

Comment: You should research on google first, there is a number of relevant results.

Comment: How are you doing it? based on colour?

Comment: Yes karthik. Based on Colour

Comment: Could you share sample images illustrating the problem and the desired outcome?

Answer (score 0):

This link below is a good example.It basically talks about how to implement Kmeans segmentation to compress image step by step.
http://popscan.blogspot.com/2013/06/image-segmentation-with-k-means.html

Comment: Kindly add answer here along with link